# silverlight receive INotifyPropertyChanged in non UI class hook

Tags: silverlight, hook, inotifypropertychanged

I've a class that raises INotifyPropertyChanged events.
I'm quite happy with databinding to UI controls, but I'd like to get these events fired into a non-UI class, but am unsure of what to register or hook into.

I know it should be simple, and it probably is, I'm just after a quick pointer down this road.

Many Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding you, but can't you just use the public event in INotifyProperyChanged to do what you want to do?

```
MyClassInstance.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) =>
{
     if (e.PropertyName == "MyProperty")
     {
          // do something
     }
};
```